# grammar question(very urgent)

Tags: grammar

I've a grammar question for the following sentence:

> Is gene therapy or stem cell therapy more likely to succeed in this field.

Does it means which therapy is more likely to succeed in this field? Gene therapy or stem cell therapy?

Or does it mean therapies like gene therapy and stem cell therapy more likely to succeed in this field than other therapies?

*************************update********************************

It's a title of an essay as an assignment given by my university.
It's not a question mark but period at the end of the sentence.
"in this field"  they mean "as a treatment for Alzeimer's disease".

Comment: Note that this site cannot make any guarantees on when or even if the question will be answered.

Comment: Advice to improve the question: Is the quoted question being asked of you or is this something you are writing and want advice on? If you are being asked, it would help if you provide the one or two sentences preceding it.  If you are writing it, which meaning do you intend it to mean? Also, is there a ? at the end?

Comment: No question mark at the end and no preceding sentence. "in this field"  they mean "as a treatment for Alzeimer's disease".  It's a title of an essay as an assignment given by my university.

Answer (score 1):

> Is gene therapy or stem cell therapy more likely to succeed in this field.

means "Which of the two therapies, gene or stem cell, is more likely to succeed?"

We know this because:

1. It's the expected question.
2. "More" is comparative, and If you aren't comparing the two therapies to each other then there is nothing you are comparing them to, making this poor grammar.
3. If you are comparing the two therapies to other things the sentence has a plural subject, and should start with "Are" instead of "Is".